# Why the dot I created is not moving?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to move a dot by pressing the right-left keys. 
Here is my main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    Graphic graphic=new Graphic();
    frame.add(graphic);

}}
```

This is the graphic class where i created the dot and I implemented KeyListener and ActionListener:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Graphic extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
private int posX = 220;
private int posY = 300;
private Timer timer;
private int delay = 8;
private int width = 500;
private int height = 500;

public Graphic() {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
    this.setSize(width, height);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(posX, posY, 20, 20);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

        if (posX <= 20) {
            posX = 20;
        } else {
            moveLeft();

        }
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if (posX >= 460) {
            posX = 460;
        } else {
            moveRight();
        }
    }
    repaint();

}

private void moveRight() {
    posX += 20;

}

private void moveLeft() {
    posX -= 20;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.start();
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
```

}

In my opinion, this should work...but it doesn't. When I press the left-right keys nothing happens and it looks like it's not "listening" my commands. So, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: In order for a `KeyListener` to work, it must not only be focusable, but also **have the input focus.** Note that in Swing, we typically use key bindings rather than a key listener. Why not use key bindings here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyListener` works if the component which has the listener has the focus. 
 JFrame has by default the focus when you display it but not a JPanel.

In the `Graphic` constructor add simply `grabFocus()` :

```
public Graphic() {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
    setFocusable(true);
    grabFocus();     
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
    this.setSize(width, height);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have tested on my machine. The problem is that it works randomly as the JFrame needs to be visible if we want that the JPanel grab the focus. Sometimes it is, other times it is not. 
`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` may solve the problem.

After adding the panel to the `JFrame`, invoke the code which grabs the focus in a `invokeLater()` method.

```
    frame.add(graphic);
    ...
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            graphic.grabFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. I have tested on my machine. I edited my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You call `repaint` method of `Component` class instead of your `paint` method.

Comment: It is a listener problem not a rendering problem.